# Optimize Time Complexity For Odd Occurrences In Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, time-complexity

I have this code that pairs same elements in an array, with the expectation that the array will have an odd length and it should return the only element that couldn't get a pair. So I wrote the code just well, and it works fine for smaller arrays, but with very large big integers of over 1 billion, the time complexity became O(N**2) and then the need to refactor my code to get a much better performance for large arrays and large array elements. Here is my code below;

```
function solution(A) {
if(!Array.isArray(A)) return 0;

var temp = new Array(A.length);
var position = 0;

for(let i=0; i<A.length; i++){
    if(temp.includes(A[i])){
        position = temp.indexOf(A[i]);
        index = A.indexOf(A[i]);
        delete temp[position];
        delete A[index];
        delete A[i];
    }else{
        temp[i] = A[i];
    }
}

for(let j=0; j<A.length; j++){
    if(A[j] !== undefined) return A[j];
    else continue;
}
}
```

To test it, source data can look like [2,3,6,7,3,5,5,6,2] and it will give an output of 7. But when the array is so large up to [1,2,....] with length n = n=999,999, or n = 5000,000,000, the time complexity increases exponentially.

Comment: Could you write source data as text and desired data as text?

Comment: @StepUp, I just edited and included the source data and desired data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use Object to store non-paired elements only.
Please note that you don't need to store all the array elements and their counts in the Object and then filter by count (like @StepUp does).

Everything's been done in a single loop.
The function returns Array of all non-paired elements:

```js
const solution = A => Array.isArray(A) ?
  Object.keys(
    A.reduce((r, k) => {
      r[k] = r[k] || 0;
      if (++r[k] > 1) delete r[k];
      return r;
    }, {})
  ) : [];

console.log(solution([2, 3, 6, 7, 3, 5, 5, 6, 2]))
```

Comment: I don't really figure out everything you did just yet, and it is returning an object of integers, how do I return just the first integer in that object?

Comment: @optimalresource, the function returns Array, you can take any of its elements by index.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out, I tried to decode everything you've done. Thanks a lot

Comment: @optimalresource, happy to help.

Comment: What a neat, beautiful, awesome algorithm! I like it! This answer should be accepted! :)

Comment: Yeah I thought about that too, it should serve as a resource for others, I tested it against all possible conditions and it stood out. Now I understand most things about maps, filters and reduce and how many ways they can be chained, because @Kosh really made me feel good, a good jump in my adrenaline after beholding the beauty.

Answer (score 1):

We can try to find odd occurrences for one iteration by using great features of object. Object is key - value pair. So access to object key is `O(1)`. So when we meet the same element, then we just increment value:

```
const hashMap = arr.reduce((a, c)=> {
  a[c] = a[c] || 0;
  a[c] += 1;
  return a;
},{})
const result = Object.keys(hashMap).filter(key => hashMap[key] === 1);
```

An example:

```js
let arr = [2, 3, 6, 7, 3, 5, 5, 6, 2];

const hashMap = arr.reduce((a, c)=> {
  a[c] = a[c] || 0;
  a[c] += 1;
  return a;
},{})
const result = Object.keys(hashMap).filter(key => hashMap[key] === 1);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This looks so good, I have been analyzing what you did, just learnt the reduce method and am able to see how that you mapped an incremented key for each value if it is paired and then for the single digit, no increment which gives us the result. But a lot of things I still need to understand in the code you just wrote. Thanks.

Comment: @optimalresource  I am glad that it helped to you! Feel free to ask any question! :)

Comment: @optimalresource please, see Kosh answer and it has O(N) complexity. My answer has complexity O(2*N). Use his answer. It is better than my. Mark his reply as answer to simplify the future search of other users. You will better performance.

Comment: Yeah I found out about the complexity, it was really cool. Have accepted it as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

My two 100% JavaScript solutions with optimized time complexity. The first one is using Set:

```
function solution(A) {

    const pairs = new Set();

    for (const num of A) {
        if (pairs.has(num)) {
            pairs.delete(num);
        } else {
            pairs.add(num);
        }
    }

    const [unpaired] = pairs;
    return unpaired;

}
```

The second one is using bitwise XOR:

```
function solution(A) {

    let unpaired;

    for (const num of A) {
        unpaired ^= num;
    }

    return unpaired;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a java example that gives 100% result in optimization and score:

```
  public static int getUnpairedElement(int[] arr) {
    if (arr == null || arr.length == 0) {
      return 0;
    }

    Arrays.sort(arr);

    int[] arrNew = new int[arr.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, arrNew, 0, arrNew.length - 1);
    arrNew[arrNew.length - 1] = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < arrNew.length; i = i + 2) {
      if (arrNew[i] != arrNew[i + 1]) {
        return arrNew[i];
      }
    }

    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).